# How I can use Object format content in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am creating a portal where I can check whether a user is satisfying a condition or not. If the user satisfies the condition then the content is visible, otherwise it stays hidden.

I have one form page where I take these conditions from the admin and store it in the database in string form. Basically, it is JSON.

That JSON stored in the database looks like this

```json
[
  {"parameter":"age","condition":"age >= 39 && age <= 149"},
  {"parameter":"gender","array": ["Male","Female","other"],"condition":"genderArray.includes(gender)"},
  {"parameter":"state","array":["Jammu and Kashmir","Arunachal Pradesh","Daman and Diu (UT)"],"condition":"stateArray.includes(state)"},
  {"parameter":"category","array":  ["ST","OBC","SC"],"condition":"categoryArray.includes(category)"}
]
```

Now I am facing a problem: How can I frame this in manner to be able to check if the user is eligible or not?

Supposing there is user data already store in the variable like: age, gender, state, category...

Is it possible to use the condition from the JSON which is stored in database and check if condition applies to the user?

Comment: It would not be trivial to implement such conditions, but It is certainly possible to interpret the JSON, parse each "condition" and check whether they are met. From a design point of view, it seems to be unjustifiably complex. What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: @istepaniuk I try to store the data in one variable but when i trying to store the data of array in other variable php throwing a error `Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\simpholic\Dashboard\home.php on line 35`

Comment: Please add the failing code to your answer. As it currently stands, the answer is very broad and it is not easy to give a concise answer.